# KineticJS Image Flip - Preserve coordinates and dimensions

Tags: image, html5-canvas, kineticjs, flip

I'm looking for where in the library images are position. I'm working with v4.5.1.

It appears that in the drawFunction for images its always placed at (0, 0).
Here is an excerpt from Kinetic.Image::drawFunction()

```
// if cropping
if(crop) {
    cropX = crop.x || 0;
    cropY = crop.y || 0;
    cropWidth = crop.width || 0;
    cropHeight = crop.height || 0;
    params = [image, cropX, cropY, cropWidth, cropHeight, 0, 0, width, height];
}
// no cropping
else {
    params = [image, 0, 0, width, height];
}
```

How does it ultimately get positioned?

I'm asking because I want to flip images and it looks like there is no method for that.

I know there are various ways to do it. I'm setting the scale to -1, but I end up having to translate the coordinates for the flipped image. I don't want to modify the coordinates or dimensions in the object attributes.

I'm using Kinetic as a foundation for a larger project and the Kinetic classes are used as base classes. I would like to just override the right method and either re-implement to account for the scale and translate before draw or pass it already translated values.

​Any help would be a great help. Thanks!

~Micah

Answer (score 2):

To flip an image, you can just apply a negative scale, like this:

```
var img = new Kinetic.Image({
  x: 50,
  y: 20,
  width: 100,
  height: 50,
  image: flipperImage,
  offsetX: 25,
  scaleX: -1
});
```

This will flip the image in the x direction (about the y axis).  You can of course use this technique with any shape, as well as groups, layers, and the entire stage.  To adjust the axis of rotation, you set the shape offset.

Here's an animated example:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-scale-animation-tutorial/

The red hexagon is flipped about the y axis.

Comment: Yeah, I started using the offset. I guess this is the proper way to use the library. I was wondering if there was a way to override a root level function. But I guess my question was more asking how to hack Kinetic lol. Which I can understand you wouldn't want. But thanks anyway! :)